# libcurl WriteMemoryCallback method don't work on iOS

Tags: ios, libcurl

I use libcurl to request data from my server.But the WriteMemoryCallback method don't work successfully.
My operating system is iOS, libcurl's version is 7.40.0.
These are my codes:

```
struct ResultStruct {
    char *memory;
    char *cookie_list;
    char *session_id;
};

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t WriteMemoryCallback(char *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, struct MemoryStruct *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    userp->memory = contents;
    if(userp->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return realsize;
}

curl_slist * get_cookies(CURL *curl)
{
    CURLcode res;
    struct curl_slist *cookies;
    printf("Cookies, curl knows:\n");
    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Curl curl_easy_getinfo failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        exit(1);
    }
    return cookies;
}

char *get_comment(char *url)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    struct MemoryStruct *chunk = new struct MemoryStruct;
    chunk->memory = new char[2000];
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, chunk);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
//    curl_global_cleanup();
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << chunk->memory << std::endl;
    char *result = new char[2000];
    result = chunk->memory;
//    delete chunk->memory;
    delete chunk;
    std::cout << "******************************************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

I have set a break point in the method WriteMemoryCallback, and I found that param contents contain the data that I need. But I set a break point in the method get_comment, I found that the param chunk lost some data. I don't know how to fix the bug.I don't find the error.I need help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the point of using libcurl on iOS could be. Why don't you use `NSURLSession` (or `NSURLConnection` if you need compatibility with iOS < 7, or AFNetwork...)? They provide much (if not all?) of the same functionality, and are better integrated with the rest of the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you use `NSURLSession` rather than `libcurl` on iOS.

However, the issue here is that WriteMemoryCallback is called multiple times as libcurl receives data. You're supposed to aggregate the data you receive from those multiple calls, but you don't, you just set `userp->memory` to point to `contents` (which is a bad idea, as you're at least supposed to copy it, `contents` is not guaranteed to still contain the relevant data once the callback returns).

You need to allocate memory and append the newly received data in `WriteMemoryCallback`.

Or use `NSURLSession`: `dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler` will do all of that for you.

Comment: You are right.I modified by program and use string.append(char *) to get the response data.And it worked.

Comment: If this answer wouldn't have the off-topic recommendation for another framework that wasn't asked for, I would upvote it...

Comment: Hey @DanielStenberg, don't get me wrong, I love curl and use it nearly daily, and when I need to do network requests in perl I definitely use WWW::Curl, but on iOS I really don't feel that for most use cases there's much reason to stray from the standard system frameworks...

Comment: That's all fine, I don't mind that at all, I just find that it was not at all what was asked.